# AWS SES ConfigurationSet Delivery Option using AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, amazon-simple-email-service

I'm struggling to fully understand the way configuration sets and their associated delivery options work.

I'm trying to ensure that each message sent via AWS SES will enforce tls encryption rather than using the default `opportunistic` approach.

As per [official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/security.html) I have created a new set using AWS cli:

```
aws ses put-configuration-set-delivery-options --configuration-set-name TlsEncryption --delivery-options TlsPolicy=Require
```

But I cannot seem to be able to verify that this delivery option is actually attached to this configuration set.

When I run

```
aws ses describe-configuration-set --configuration-set-name=TlsEncryption
```

I only get

```
{
  "ConfigurationSet": {
    "Name": "TlsEncryption"
  }
}
```

therefore I'm unsure whether the delivery option has been actually set on it and will work with each call when using `X-SES-CONFIGURATION-SET: TlsEncryption` or not.

Could someone shine some light on it please?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this Sebastian?

Comment: I didn't - I just send the request specifying delivery options with each request because I simply cannot verify that the given set will use it automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's buried in the AWS CLI enumerations.

```
aws ses describe-configuration-set --configuration-set-name tls-config-set --configuration-set-attribute-names deliveryOptions --region=eu-west-1
```

Note, the magic enum is deliveryOptions

```
{
    "ConfigurationSet": {
        "Name": "tls-config-set"
    },
    "DeliveryOptions": {
        "TlsPolicy": "Require"
    }
}
```

Comment: Sweet - thanks very much. Could you add the link to where you've found it in the docs please?